# Create a new fixed size array in solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity

What is the difference between the below two array?

without `new` keyword: `bool[3] fixedArray;`

with `new` keyword: `bool[] fixedArray2 = new bool[](3);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `new` keyword is used to initialise arrays *in memory*. From the docs:

> **Allocating Memory Arrays**
>
> Creating arrays with variable length in
>   memory can be done using the new keyword. As opposed to storage
>   arrays, it is not possible to resize memory arrays by assigning to the
>   .length member.
>
> ```
> pragma solidity ^0.4.16;
>
> contract C {
>     function f(uint len) public pure {
>         uint[] memory a = new uint[](7);
>         bytes memory b = new bytes(len);
>         // Here we have a.length == 7 and b.length == len
>         a[6] = 8;
>     }
> }
> ```